# statsmodels get_margeff() for OLS

Tags: statsmodels

statsmodels does not seem to support stata-like margins after an OLS regression.

There is no get_margeff() method for linear_model.RegressionResults or linear_model.RegressionResults.model. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Just want to make sure before I start writing stata-like margins methods for OLS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, statsmodels does not have margins for OLS (partially for GLM-gaussian). But margins in a linear model like OLS are just the params.

Comment: While this is true for linear terms like x1 or x2, it is not true for non-linear terms like quadratics or interaction terms. The differential, dy/dx for these terms depend on the value of an independent variable. The values can be evaluated 1) at means, 2) at a list of values for the independent variable, or 3) at all values. In the last case, the mean marginal effect is reported. These operations are supported for OLS and Logit by the Stata margins command and in R by the marginaleffects package. 
So, given your answer I will have to write them.

Comment: Even the current statsmodels margeff cannot handle multi column terms. The problem is to obtain the correct information from the formula.

Comment: The development version (and upcoming release) has a new `get_prediction` method and related infrastructure with delta method for nonlinear functions for use cases like this. However, support for user provided functions  is not yet public, functions are currently for internal use.

Comment: (I just looked at this a bit). In linear models, even multi-column effects like interactions or polynomials are linear in parameters, so we can use the t_test method for inference. However, statsmodels does not have support for creating the exog for this from the formulas. statsmodels issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5387

Comment: I changed the language of my question to be more precise. Note that the statsmodels get_margineff() method after a logistic regression looks just like the Stata margins command. The Stata margins command calculates what are called Average Margins & Average Marginal effects using numerical differentiation for dydx, eydx, and eyex options.

Comment: I changed the language of my question to be more precise. Note that the statsmodels get_margineff() method after a logistic regression looks just like the Stata margins command. The Stata margins command calculates what are called Average Margins & Average Marginal effects using numerical differentiation of the data for dydx, eydx, and eyex options. I am almost finished testing a stata-like margins solution that is adequate for my purpose for post-statsmodels-regression. I can post it when it is complete sometime next week (about 10/19/22).

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The standard error and confidence intervals for the marginal effects for quadratics and interaction terms are obtained from statsmodels using the variance-covariance matrix that is retrieved with the cov_params() method on the RegressionResults object. Using the variances and covariances in the CV matrix, apply the standard formula for Var(aX + bY). Log terms are not as easy. There are formulas from calculus but, marginal effects for log terms are typically obtained using a Stata-like margins capability.